# Lambda type inference and implicit conversions

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I've defined a the following class:

```
class TransparentFunction1[-T1, +R1](val func : T1 => R1, val text : String) {
  @inline
  def apply(t : T1) = func(t)

  override def toString = text
}
```

Basically, `TransparentFunction1` is just a wrapper around a `Function1` that provides a human-readable text field describing what the function is.

I'd like to define an implicit conversion that can convert any Function1 into a `TransparentFunction1`, passing the function's code to the text parameter.

I've defined such an implicit conversion using a macro:

```
  implicit def transparentFunction1[T1, R1](expression : T1 => R1) : TransparentFunction1[T1, R1] = macro Macros.transparentImpl[T1, R1, TransparentFunction1[T1, R1]]

object Macros {
  def transparentImpl[T : context.WeakTypeTag, U : context.WeakTypeTag, V : context.WeakTypeTag](context : scala.reflect.macros.whitebox.Context) (expression : context.Expr[T => U]) : context.Expr[V] = {
      import context.universe._
      context.Expr[V](
        Apply(
          Select(
            New(
              TypeTree(
                appliedType(weakTypeOf[V].typeConstructor, weakTypeOf[T] :: weakTypeOf[U] :: Nil)
              )
            ),
            termNames.CONSTRUCTOR
          ),
          List(expression.tree, Literal(Constant(expression.tree.toString)))
        )
      )
    }
}
```

This works.  However, it causes a problem for type inference.

For example, if I try to call a method named "map" that takes an argument of type `TransparentFunction1[Int, Int]` like this:

```
map(_ + 2)
```

I get an error "missing parameter type for expanded function", whereas if map's parameter type was just `Int => Int`, the type inference works correctly.

Is there a way to fix the macro so that type inference will continue to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this you only need to have `TransparentFunction1` extend `Function1` (which seems natural anyway, given that `TransparentFunction1` is conceptually very much a `Function1`, it just adds a custom `toString` but should otherwise act as a plain funciton):

```
class TransparentFunction1[-T1, +R1](val func : T1 => R1, val text : String) extends (T1 => R1){
  @inline
  def apply(t : T1) = func(t)

  override def toString = text
}
```

There  are only a handfull of reasons I can see for defining a function-like class that does **not** extend `Function1`. Off the top of my head the main reason is when your class is designed to be used as implicit values (eg a type class), and you don't want to have the compiler automatically use those implicit values as implicit conversions (which it will if it extends `Function1`). It does not seem to be the case here so having `TransparentFunction1` extend `Function1` seems the right thing to do.

Comment: (smacks forehead) Don't know why I didn't think of that.  Preliminarily, that seems to fix the problem.  I have to experiment with the macro to be sure.

Comment: Ow ... that is ... very surprising. There's no reason that type inference should be able to infer the types in that case but not in the OP's example. This looks like an implementation artifact ^^ But good news for you, then :)

Comment: It actually does make some sense.  When the compiler sees the lambda, it looks at the method's parameter type.  Since the expected parameter type is a kind of Function1[T, R], it can know from the first type argument, T, that the _ parameter is of type Int.  If the types were unrelated, it has no way of inferring the lambda's type until the implicit conversion is applied.  But, it can't find the implicit conversion because it doesn't know what type its converting from yet.   Chicken and egg.  The inference algorithm probably could be adjusted to accommodate, but that would be complex.

Comment: @Nimrand: Actually sjrd is onto something. Your rationale is good in that it explains how it is done in the compiler and why it compiles. But is it logical really? There's an implicit conversion here, from `A` to `B` (`A = Int=>Int]`, `B =TransparentFunction1[Int, Int]`). It is `B` that will have to match the expected argument type, **not** `A`! And yet the compiler infers the type of the function literal from `A`! So yes, having `TransparentFunction1` extend `Function1` allows the code to compile (and is the natural thing to do anyway), but there **is** something fishy going on apparently.

Comment: To illustrate this inconsistency, try to modify the implicit conversion to always return a `TransparentFunction1[Float, Float]` irrespective of the input `Function1`'s argument and return types. The function literal will still be inferred to a `Function1[Int, Int]` just because the `map` method expects a `Function1[Int, Int]` (precisely, a `TransparentFunction1[Int, Int]`), even though the actual conversion that is applied later will return a `TransparentFunction1[Float, Float]`. And sure enough, in the end you still get a type mismatch error because the implicit conversion  is unapplicable.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  It's a bit broken.  It comes to the correct inference for essentially the wrong reason.  But, I think for most use cases it's the correct outcome.  So, I wasn't going to complain!  Your counter example would be an unusual use case.  I can think of a way to "fix" the inference algorithm to clean this up and still make my use case work.  When i have time, I think I'll submit a proposal to change this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a way to do that. I've tried, some time ago, to do the same thing for `js.FunctionN` in Scala.js (e.g., implicitly convert a `T1 => R` into a `js.Function1[T1, R]`), and I could never make the type inference work for the parameters of the lambda. It seems to be impossible, unfortunately.

Comment: Have you tried having `js.Function1` extend `scala.Function1`? Or is there in your case a good reason not to (in OP's case I don't think there is)?

Comment: For Scala.js that is not an option. If it were, there would be no reason not to use `scala.FunctionN` in the first place ;-) I can't really elaborate on Scala.js' reasons in an SO comment, though. It's pretty deep. That said, I do not believe extending in that direction would help solve the type inference issue, because the lambda expression would be a supertype of the expected type, and would therefore still need the implicit conversion, through which the inferencer seems unable to look for parameter types.

Comment: Too bad. But for what it's worth, extending `Function1` **does** help. In OP's case, it's all that is needed to make `map(_ + 2)` compile.

Comment: Sorry to insist, but are you **sure** that you can't have `js.Function1` extend `scala.Function1`? I understand that you cannot just use `scala.Function1` where you are using `js.Function1`, but that does not mean that `js.Function1` cannot extend `scala.Function1`. I've never implied that `js.Function1` is not needed at all.

Comment: I am absolutely certain. A `js.Function1` is a JavaScript `function`. It doesn't have any of the methods, nor the semantics, that `scala.Function1` is supposed to provide. So it cannot be a subtype of `scala.Function1`.

Comment: Understood. Sorry for bugging you, and thanks for making scala.js :-). You got me curious though, I'll have a look at how `js.Function1` fits in scala.js, maybe there is a not so obvious way to make it work as in OP's case (probably not, but eh, it's worth another look).